# Install-AdServiceAccount The server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

I have two servers.

1. AD Server (ADServer.adqa.myDomain.com, machine name ADServer)
2. Web Server (Linked to that AD server, machine name WEBSERVER)

My goal is to create a managed service account on AD server and link it with a web server. The web server is already attached to AD server.

I ran the following command on my web server to create a managed service account:

New-ADServiceAccount -name myServiceAccount -DNSHostName ADServer.adqa.mydomain.com -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword "CN=WEBSERVER,CN=Computers,DC=adqa,DC=mydomain,DC=com"

There is no issue till this point.

When I run the Install-AdServiceAccount on my web server I get "The server has rejected the client credentials" error. Here is the command I ran on web server:

```
PS C:\Users\raghav> Install-AdServiceAccount myServiceAccount
Install-AdServiceAccount : The server has rejected the client credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-AdServiceAccount myServiceAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Install-ADServiceAccount], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.A
   ctiveDirectory.Management.Commands.InstallADServiceAccount
```

I have already restarted the web server. Can you share which permission I am missing on AD or Web server which I can run it so that the web server can run Install-AdServiceAccount command succesfully?

Here is the output of "Get-ADServiceAccount" command on AD Server for your reference:
Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity myServiceAccount -Properties *

```
AccountExpirationDate                      :
accountExpires                             : 9223372036854775807
AccountLockoutTime                         :
AccountNotDelegated                        : False
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption          : False
AuthenticationPolicy                       : {}
AuthenticationPolicySilo                   : {}
BadLogonCount                              : 0
badPasswordTime                            : 0
badPwdCount                                : 0
CannotChangePassword                       : False
CanonicalName                              : adqa.myDomain.com/Managed Service Accounts/myServiceAccount
Certificates                               : {}
CN                                         : myServiceAccount
codePage                                   : 0
CompoundIdentitySupported                  : {False}
countryCode                                : 0
Created                                    : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
createTimeStamp                            : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
Deleted                                    :
Description                                :
DisplayName                                :
DistinguishedName                          : CN=myServiceAccount,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=adqa,DC=myDomain,DC=com
DNSHostName                                : ADServer.adqa.myDomain.com
DoesNotRequirePreAuth                      : False
dSCorePropagationData                      : {1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM}
Enabled                                    : True
HomedirRequired                            : False
HomePage                                   :
HostComputers                              : {}
instanceType                               : 4
isCriticalSystemObject                     : False
isDeleted                                  :
KerberosEncryptionType                     : {RC4, AES128, AES256}
LastBadPasswordAttempt                     :
LastKnownParent                            :
lastLogoff                                 : 0
lastLogon                                  : 0
LastLogonDate                              :
localPolicyFlags                           : 0
LockedOut                                  : False
logonCount                                 : 0
ManagedPasswordIntervalInDays              : {30}
MemberOf                                   : {}
MNSLogonAccount                            : False
Modified                                   : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
modifyTimeStamp                            : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
msDS-GroupMSAMembership                    : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity
msDS-ManagedPasswordId                     : {1, 0, 0, 0...}
msDS-ManagedPasswordInterval               : 30
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes              : 28
msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed         : 0
Name                                       : myServiceAccount
nTSecurityDescriptor                       : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity
ObjectCategory                             : CN=ms-DS-Group-Managed-Service-Account,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=adqa,DC=myDomain,DC=com
ObjectClass                                : msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount
ObjectGUID                                 : 7ef8485b-f7a9-4fe5-b316-6dd4362fb461
objectSid                                  : S-1-5-21-262313328-3322894162-140377554-4084
PasswordExpired                            : False
PasswordLastSet                            : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
PasswordNeverExpires                       : False
PasswordNotRequired                        : False
PrimaryGroup                               : CN=Domain Computers,CN=Users,DC=adqa,DC=myDomain,DC=com
primaryGroupID                             : 515
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount       : {}
PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword : {CN=WEBSERVERQA,CN=Computers,DC=adqa,DC=myDOmain,DC=com}
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion            : False
pwdLastSet                                 : 132609111812542391
SamAccountName                             : myServiceAccount$
sAMAccountType                             : 805306369
sDRightsEffective                          : 15
ServicePrincipalNames                      :
SID                                        : S-1-5-21-262313328-3322894162-140377554-4084
SIDHistory                                 : {}
TrustedForDelegation                       : False
TrustedToAuthForDelegation                 : False
UseDESKeyOnly                              : False
userAccountControl                         : 4096
userCertificate                            : {}
UserPrincipalName                          :
uSNChanged                                 : 1995835
uSNCreated                                 : 1995832
whenChanged                                : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
whenCreated                                : 3/22/2021 6:26:21 PM
```

I am already running the PowerShell command using elavated (Run as admin) mode.

Comment: Is this your first gMSA?  How long ago did you setup the kds root key?

Comment: Yes, this the first one.

Comment: Well, by now, if it’s been 10 hours, you may want to try again; haven’t dug in too much, but it may be that you didn’t set up the kds root key for immediate use; by default you need to wait 10 hours after creating it before using gMSAs.

Comment: Unfortinately, it is still not working after that interval.